# Maven deploy exclude logback.xml file

Tags: maven, logback

I have a maven project that uses logback, and it has a logback.xml file. The project is meant to run on it's own. But I have another maven project that needs to use a couple of classes from the first project. So when I deploy my first maven project, how do I exclude the logback.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

There should be one `logback.xml` per application. If you have this sort of issue, it probably means that one application includes another, which suggests a design error.

Consider making these "couple of classes" a separate library, so you can use them from both applications. And remove the dependency between your two executable units.